# weird fonts rendering on chrome and firefox (windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, fonts

Lately I'm experiencing a weird issue with fonts in Chrome (latest) and Firefox (latest), everything looks "crisp" and not "smooth".

this *does not* happens on IE and Edge, as you can see on the picture below.
I've tried enabling "DirectWrite" under chrome's flags in the past but without any success (chrome 52  no longer supports this flag)

any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

---

**EDIT : just so you can see how weird it looks here's another website[image]**

Comment: Is ClearType enabled system-wide? Last I knew Windows had options for ClearType in browser that were separate (or could be enabled separately) from the system overall. No font smoothing in non-Microsoft browsers seems like this could be part of your issue.

Answer (score 2):

eventually found a solution on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3f7xfk/psa_solution_to_blurry_text_on_125_dpi_in_windows/) , TLDR : download and use [This](http://windows10_dpi_blurry_fix.xpexplorer.com/)

**EDIT : apparently it "ClearType" which made the difference (Start-> "ClearType Text"), just remember to reboot!**